# Redis in-service authentication enablement

Tags: authentication, redis

I have a redis infrastructure running already with no authentication enabled. I need to enable authentication due to security concerns. But the applications which connects to redis needs to be updated about the redis password and redis restart also required. This enablement requires a downtime. Is there any option available in redis to enable the authentication in-service. Or is there any transistion state where redis can accept both authenticated and un-authenticated request so that we can plan the auth in 2 phase approach?

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible** to enable authentication without restart. Best option is to replicate data to slave and serve from slave then you can enable authentication in master.

For accepting both authenticated and un-authenticated commands you can create a wrapper around redis driver for creating a new client with authenticated request when authentication fails.

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any option available in redis to enable the authentication in-service

You can use the `config set requirepass password` to enable authentication on the fly. However, after that, your client has to use the `AUTH` command to send the new password to Redis.

**NOTE**: After restart of Redis, the password set by `config set` command will gone. So you must also set the password in config file.

> Or is there any transistion state where redis can accept both authenticated and un-authenticated request

You can take a look at Redis 6.0's [ACL](https://cn.bing.com/search?q=redis+6.0+acl&go=%E6%8F%90%E4%BA%A4&qs=n&form=QBLHCN&sp=-1&pq=redis+6.0+acl&sc=0-13&sk=&cvid=A93730C4182D485286FA33BC676C80BC), which support different ACL control for different users.

**NOTE**: Redis 6.0 is still in pre-release stage.